# What is Hurricane's accuracy in rain?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series

With no weather active, Hurricane has an accuracy of 70%. In the rain, however, the accuracy of the attack is boosted. Serebii states that its accuracy becomes 100%.

> This move has different accuracies depending upon the weather. In Rain, it has an accuracy of 100%. – [Serebii.net AttackDex](http://serebii.net/attackdex-bw/hurricane.shtml)

Veekun and Psypoke both confirm this as well.

> During Rain Dance, this move has 100% accuracy. – [Veekun](http://veekun.com/dex/moves/Hurricane)
>
> During Rain Dance, it becomes 100% accurate. – [Psypoke](http://www.psypokes.com/dex/techdex/542)

However, Bulbapedia states that Hurricane "cannot miss" in the rain (emphasis mine).

> Hurricane **cannot miss** when used during heavy rain, but has an accuracy of 50% during intense sunlight. – [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hurricane)

This is slightly unclear. It could be trying to state that Hurricane has a 100% accuracy and therefore cannot miss *unless* the attacker's accuracy or defender's evasion have been modified. It could also be trying to say Hurricane is unable to miss in the rain, similar to [Aerial Ace](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aerial_Ace) and other similar moves. **Does Hurricane have 100% accuracy in the rain, or can it not miss?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's looking a bit difficult to get a straight answer here, even when comparing to the similar-mechanic moves Blizzard and Thunder.

Bulbapedia says that those three moves cannot miss when used in the correct weather, while Psypoke agrees for Blizzard and Thunder - though it says Hurricane has just 100% accuracy. Serebii gives 100% accuracy to Hurricane and Thunder and ignores Blizzard's weather-based accuracy outright, while Veekun gives 100% accuracy to all three moves.

The interesting bit is Smogon. [Its moveslist](http://www.smogon.com/bw/moves/thunder) gives the three moves 100% accuracy in the correct weather. However, there are two catches:

1. In its Gen IV sections, it gives the weather-enhanced accuracy of Blizzard and Thunder as "cannot miss".
2. From http://www.smogon.com/forums/showthread.php?t=79340:

   > Hurricane has its accuracy boosted to 100% in rain and reduced to 50% in Sun; its accuracy remains 70% in all other weather. Its accuracy in rain is Swift=like, bypassing accuracy drops and evasion boosts.

[One of the posts in that topic](http://www.smogon.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3052246&postcount=1018) explains: "My Vaporeon with Wind Storm [Japanese version of Hurricane] didn't miss after 16 tries with a -6 Stage Accuracy during Rain."

At -6 accuracy, a 100% move is running at 33%, so the odds of hitting 16/16 times are 1 in 43,046,721. So, taking that research thread at face value - and they've the people that decoded the damage formula if I'm not mistaken - then **I have to conclude that, like Blizzard in hail and Thunder in rain, Hurricane has infinite accuracy in rain.**

Footnote: I remember seeing somewhere during this research that Gen V represents cannot-miss moves with an accuracy of "101%". If you're using an extraction tool that assumes 100% is the maximum (which I would guess some of these sites do), you might get an invalid answer.

Comment: Great answer; this is exactly the kind of evidence I was looking for.